# Capturing and injecting HttpRequestMessage in Web API with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

I've got a class that requires access to the HttpRequestMessage in my Web API service. At the moment, I've got the following code to capture the message in the pipeline and save it for later (based on [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/04/19/WiringHttpControllerContextWithCastleWindsor/) and [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/)):

```cs
public class ContextCapturingControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;
    private HttpRequestMessage requestMessage;

    public ContextCapturingControllerActivator(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, 
                                  HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, 
                                  Type controllerType)
    {
        this.kernel.Rebind<HttpRequestMessage>()
            .ToConstant<HttpRequestMessage>(requestMessage);

        var controller = (IHttpController)this.kernel.GetService(controllerType);

        this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
        requestMessage.RegisterForDispose(
            new Release(() => this.kernel.Release(controller)));

        return controller; 
    }

    private class Release : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Action release;

        public Release(Action release)
        {
            this.release = release;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.release();
        }
    }
}
```

In my composition root, I configure the `ControllerActivator`:

```cs
kernel.Bind<IHttpControllerActivator>()
      .To<ContextCapturingControllerActivator>();
```

The end result is that from the perspective of the configuration, the `HttpRequestMessage` is "magically" injected wherever it is requested since it is done for us inside the `ControllerActivator`. I have not been able to inject the message from my composition root. I'm also not crazy about the Rebind since it's there to avoid adding a new binding every time the service is called. I suspect it's due to the singleton nature of the Web API stack, but have not been able to sort out how to deal with that properly.

In general, I cannot use the latest unstable Nuget package of Ninject web api due to the error reported (and ignored) [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ninject/rC2vhj8yvBU/NAIkNA-QrAAJ).

Can anyone suggest the proper way to improve my code to make it a bit more clear and make life easier for future maintainers (and let's face it -- that's probably going to be me).

Thanks.

Comment: I've had to do the same recently with Ninject (and previously with StructureMap) and have yet to find a better solution.

Comment: @BenFoster I've since switched to Autofac (for many reasons, not just this issue), and while it provides a cleaner way to inject the HttpRequestMessage into running code, I haven't been able to access it in my in-memory integration tests. So, each DI framework seems to have its own unique trade-offs.

Comment: Any break through? I have the same problem...

Comment: I have the same problem. Using this solution above causes my CPU to spike to 100 because the bindings are stored in a static dictionary. When multiple requests come through, they are contending because of each thread's attempt to enumerate the dictionary. :( Anyone find another way of doing this? @Hudvoy? @BenFoster?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, but I believe it depends on Web API 2.0+.

I created an instance class that wraps the current context's http request:

```
public class HttpRequestMessageWrapper
{
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage m_httpRequestMessage;

    public HttpRequestMessageWrapper()
    {
        m_httpRequestMessage = HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;
    }

    public HttpRequestMessage RequestMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return m_httpRequestMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I bound the HttpRequestMessage to the property with the ToMethod binding in request scope.

```
container.Bind<HttpRequestMessage>().ToMethod(ctx => new HttpRequestMessageWrapper().RequestMessage).InRequestScope();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the method that @Mackers proposed which is the cleanest way.... however, in my specific scenario, it didn't work due to a timing issue. For my case, I needed to inject an object into the apicontroller ctor and that object required the HttpRequestMessage. The `HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"]`isn't populated until the controller has been constructed and initialized and I couldn't find any other way to access it. So I resorted to creating a custom DelegatingHandler and rebinding the current request message as they come in.

```
public class CurrentHttpRequestMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            UpdateScopeWithHttpRequestMessage(request);

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        internal static void UpdateScopeWithHttpRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            NinjectConfig.GetConfiguredKernel().Rebind<HttpRequestMessage>().ToMethod(ctx => { return request; })
                .InRequestScope();
        }
    }
```

The GetConfiguredKernel is a static method I created to simply return the static Kernel instance already configured.

```
 public class NinjectConfig
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        private static StandardKernel _kernel;

        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        public static IKernel GetConfiguredKernel()
        {
            if (_kernel != null)
                return _kernel;

            return CreateKernel();
        }
        ....
```

Then register the DelegatingHandler with the HttpConfiguration:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CurrentHttpRequestMessageHandler());
```

Answer (score -1):

Building off of Macker's answer, System.Web has an [HttpRequestBase class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase?view=netframework-4.7.2) that you can use and simplify unit testing the code. Anywhere in the code that the request is required, specify the HttpRequestBase type as the constructor parameter and register it with the below method:

Ninject example:

```
Bind<HttpRequestBase>().ToMethod(context => new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request));
```

Unity example:

```
container.RegisterType<HttpRequestBase>(new InjectionFactory(_ => new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request)));
```